# update page with localstorage value angular watcher

Tags: javascript, angularjs

controller 1 where we set value

```
$scope.view = function() {
    $scope.usethis = "&1=test";
    $localStorage.change = $scope.usethis;
}
```

Now in my second controller I grab the value to update:

```
$scope.Data = function() {

var URL;
$scope.update = $localStorage.change;
URL = "?test";
        if ($scope.update){
            URL = "?test" + $scope.update;          
            }
}
```

and finally my watcher:

```
 $scope.$watch(function () { return $localStorage.change; },function(newVal,oldVal) { 
    if(oldVal!==newVal) { 
$scope.update = newVal;
} }) ;
```

On page refresh I can update the query, it uses the values as required. However it does not update without a refresh, so wondering if an issue with the watcher.